# Activate HDMI output without using as desktop

Tags: xorg, pulseaudio, intel, hdmi

I have an Intel card, and it appears that [it is not possible to just stream audio and no video](https://superuser.com/a/483737/124560). So is there a way to just activate the port and send a dummy video signal to have audio working? I do not want to extend my desktop on the additional screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a second X display for the HDMI output. This will still use up video RAM and display it, but it will be separate from your primary desktop, so your desktop stays on your monitor and doesn't extend to the additional screen. I've set this up on my Intel integrated graphics with an `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file that contains

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "intel0"
    Driver "intel"
    Option "AccelMethod" "sna"
    Option "ZaphodHeads" "VGA1,HDMI1,DP1"
    Screen 0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "intel1"
    Driver "intel"
    Option "AccelMethod" "sna"
    Option "ZaphodHeads" "HDMI3"
    Screen 1
EndSection
```

You can add `Screen` sections to specify the resolution if you want.

You'll probably need different output names, look at the output of `xrandr` to see what outputs your card has. I don't remember why I had to specify the `AccelMethod`, maybe it was to make it work on my particular chipset. The first screen will have the display name `:0`, the second on the HDMI port `:1` (so you can still tell programs to make use of it if you want to by adding options like `-display :1` when you run them).

I'm using two instances of the `fvwm` window manager for each display; possibly you may need to tell your window manager to only use the first display.

Comment: I wish I could avoid starting a second X server though, not because of the ram usage but because it requires static configuration and I'm doing this just sporadically from a laptop.

Comment: There's no second X server involved (that would require *two* xorg.conf files, and the displays would be `0:0` and `1:0`). You run *one* server that drives *two* screens. I too only use the HDMI output sporadically (though this is my Desktop machine), and really the only ressource used is more video RAM. No need to turn it off if you don't need it.